# Why can't I use Current_timestamp as default value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I has a MySQL database set up locally with phpmyadmin. I wanted to use the available tables in a remote database, so I exported the SQL from phpmyadmin and tried to run it on the other DB.

This is what the export gave me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Message` text NOT NULL,
  `MsgType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Important` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Poster` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=37 ;
```

However, now it complains that there is a parse error

> near 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFA".

It worked on my local db, why not here? What changed and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I've tried using other functions like NOW() or CURDATE() as well, same problem.

Comment: Which version is the remote mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html):

> Note In older versions of MySQL (prior to 4.1), the properties of the
>   TIMESTAMP data type differed significantly in several ways from what
>   is described in this section (see the MySQL 3.23, 4.0, 4.1 Reference
>   Manual for details); these include syntax extensions which are
>   deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and no longer supported in MySQL 5.5. This
>   has implications for performing a dump and restore or replicating
>   between MySQL Server versions.

MySQL 4.0.24 is incredibly outdated, at this point - consider migrating to a version that starts with a 5. :-)

Comment: I've found the answer through your link, pre-4.1 MySQL just defaults a timestamp column to the current time without having to add the additional syntax, it seems. 

I've also been planning on informing the owners of the server about how ancient that thing is. It's still running PHP 4 as well!

Comment: It's worth noting that newer versions of MySQL also default the first TIMESTAMP column in a table to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, _unless you specify otherwise_.